# Please Explain onFinishLayout sample code?

Tags: android

I have made a class file that extends linearlayout and in one of the example of this I seen following code that I cannot understand whats its need and important.

```
protected void onFinishInflate() 
{
    super.onFinishInflate();
    ((Activity)getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.twotext, this);
    setItems();//this is my method that i have declared below this code
}
```

Comment: Which line of code don't you understand?

Comment: why don't refer in documentation.. everything is given there.. and better accept answers before u ask some other question..

Answer (score 0):

It will be called when the inflation in your layout is complete..to Just set the items on it..

For complete details please read the documentation ...